# Yeo-Johnson and Logarithmic transformation

Tags: data-transformation, biostatistics, logarithm

Is a Yeo-Johnson transformation using a lambda equal to 0 the same transformation as a logarithmic transformation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost. For a vector $U,$ the Yeo-Johnson with $\lambda=0$ is equivalent to  the natural logarithm of $( U + 1 ).$

Comment: Welcome to our site--thanks for answering so clearly! (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the warm message, and thanks for formatting my post!